# Geometric reason why this determinant can be factored to (x-y)(y-z)(z-x)?

Tags: geometry, determinant

The determinant $\begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 1 &1 \\ 
    x & y & z \\
    x^2 & y^2 &z^2 \\
  \end{vmatrix}$ can be factored to the form $(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$

---

**Proof:**

Subtracting column 1 from column 2, and putting that in column  2,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 &1 \\ 
x & y & z \\
x^2 & y^2 &z^2 \\
\end{vmatrix} 
= 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 &1 \\ 
x & y-x & z \\
x^2 & y^2-x^2 &z^2 \\
\end{vmatrix} 
\end{equation*}

$
= z^2(y-x)-z(y^2-x^2)+x(y^2-x^2)-x^2(y-x)
$

rearranging the terms,

$
=z^2(y-x)-x^2(y-x)+x(y^2-x^2)-z(y^2-x^2)
$

taking out the common terms $(y-x)$ and $(y^2-x^2)$,

$
=(y-x)(z^2-x^2)+(y^2-x^2)(x-z)
$

expanding the terms $(z^2-x^2)$ and $(y^2-x^2)$

$
=(y-x)(z-x)(z+x)+(y-x)(y+x)(x-z)
$

$
=(y-x)(z-x)(z+x)-(y-x)(z-x)(y+x)
$

taking out the common term (y-x)(z-x)

$
=(y-x)(z-x) [z+x-y-x]
$

$
=(y-x)(z-x)(z-y)
$

$
=(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)
$

---

Is there a geometric reason for this?

The determinant of this matrix is the volume of a parallelopiped with sides as vectors whose tail is at the origin and head at x,y,z coordinates being equal to the columns(or rows) of the matrix.$^{[1]}$

**So is the volume of this parallelopiped equals $(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$ in any obvious geometric way?**

---

References

[1] Nykamp DQ, “The relationship between determinants and area or volume.” From Math Insight. http://mathinsight.org/relationship_determinants_area_volume

Comment: Consider the determinant $D$ as a quadratic in $X$ : Let $D= Ax^2+Bx +C$ where $A,B,C$  depend on $y,z$ but not on $x.$   If $y\ne z$ then the zeroes of this quadratic are $y,z,$ as can be seen by looking at $D$. So $D=A(x-y)(x-z)$ whenever $y\ne z$. And the co-efficient $A$ of $ x^2$ in $D$ is $z-y.$

Comment: The question in the title and in the body are not quite the same. Maybe you could try to clarify?

Comment: @HansLundmark I don't quite understand what you mean...Maybe you suggest a better title?

Comment: It's clear why the determinant can be factored like that – you've even given a proof yourself! So it seems like you have already answered your own question (as it's formulated in the title). You might want to come up with a title that makes clear that you are looking for a geometric rather than an algebraic explanation, maybe involving the words "geometric" and/or "volume".

Comment: @HansLundmark Ok,thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Since $x=y, y=z, z=x$ give thre determinant $D$ as the determinant as zero, and it being  homogeneous cubic (see the product of diagonal element), D needs to be
$D=A(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$. Further, set $z=0, x=1,y=2$ to get $A=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting a multiple of another column (or row) to an
existing column (or row) does not change the determinant.
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
x & y & z \\
x^2 & y^2 & z^2 \\
\end{vmatrix} $$
$$= 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 &0 \\ 
x & y-x & z-x \\
x^2 & y^2-x^2 &z^2-x^2 \\
\end{vmatrix}$$
$$= 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 &0 \\ 
0 & y-x & z-x \\
0 & y^2-x^2 &z^2-x^2 \\
\end{vmatrix}$$
$$={(y-x)(z-x) 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & y+x &z+x \\
\end{vmatrix} }
$$
$$=(y-x)(z-x) 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & y+x & z-y \\
\end{vmatrix} 
$$
$$=(y-x)(z-x)(z-y)$$

Comment: Even though this is not an answer to my question, it is helpful.So thanks...

Comment: I subtracted suitable multiples of row 1 from rows 2 and 3 to get the zeros. A geometric reason why the row & column operations don't change volume would answer your question.